# Opening file in share mode as in WinAPI

Tags: winapi, rust

I'm trying to open a file in `FILE_SHARE_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` modes with the native IO library, but it seem to not exist as an option.

I tried to use the `OpenOptions` struct but it seems to lack the option of shared read/write.

Does anyone know a way around without using `winapi`/`windows-rs` crates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to use the `OpenOptions` struct but it seems to lack the option of shared read/write.

On Windows, `OpenOptions` implements the [`std::os::windows::fs::OpenOptionsExt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/fs/trait.OpenOptionsExt.html) trait, which has a [`share_mode()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/fs/trait.OpenOptionsExt.html#tymethod.share_mode) method, eg:

```
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::os::windows::prelude::*;

let file = OpenOptions::new()
    .share_mode(FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE)
    ...
    .open("file.ext");
```

Note that the share mode already includes `FILE_SHARE_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` by default.

Comment: Note that `OpenOptions` implements [`OpenOptionsExt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#impl-OpenOptionsExt-for-OpenOptions-2) when compiling for windows, so you can just use `share_mode` on `OpenOptions` (so long as you pulled in the trait).